# How can I automate copy operations before Git commits?

Tags: git, gitlab, jekyll, githooks

**Context:** I want to create a Jekyll collaborative blog. I created a subtree to insulate the collaborative portion of it from the rest of the site. However, as those goes into `_posts`, any blobs there are ignored when Jekyll renders the site.

Now, what I do is to copy everything from a specific folder (`_posts/assets/`) to `assets/`, so Jekyll can use those files after rendering the site.

I'm using Gitlab to host Jekyll, so I need to have this ***before*** pushing to Gitlab, so I do manually this now by do

```
cp -R _posts/assets/* assets
git add -A
git commit "New files for articles"
```

Can I put this on pre-commit hook so I can automate this process? Any tips?

Comment: Take a look at the [githooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), you can make scripts run automatically before the end of the push operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the git hooks available to you:

```bash
$ cd ~/project_name
$ ls -1 .git/hooks/
applypatch-msg.sample
commit-msg.sample
fsmonitor-watchman.sample
post-update.sample
pre-applypatch.sample
pre-commit.sample
pre-merge-commit.sample
prepare-commit-msg.sample
pre-push.sample
pre-rebase.sample
pre-receive.sample
update.sample
```

You're saying you want to execute a script pre-push (before pushing to GitLab). So, create a `pre-push` git hook script, and make it executable.

```bash
$ touch .git/hooks/pre-push
$ chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-push
```

Then, put your commands in that file.

`.git/hooks/pre-push`:

```
#!/bin/sh

cp -R _posts/assets/* assets
git add -A
git commit "New files for articles"
exit 0
```

Comment: using this, the last git commit makes an infine loop :(

Comment: Try adding an `exit 0` as the last command.

Comment: Note that the pre-push hook is invoked *after* `git push` has connect to the remote and chosen which commits to send—so any new commit you add here won't be sent this time! A better strategy is not to run `git push` *directly* at all: run your own script that makes the commit(s) you want and then runs `git push`.